# Переопределить 404 в tornado web

Tags: tornado, веб-программирование, http-status-code-404, python

По умолчанию tornado выдаёт 404 ошибку простой надписью "404: Not Found".

Как подставить вместо этого свой шаблон? что нужно переопределить? Или где указать это в настройках?

P.S. Версия 2.4, но значения не имеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPD**: в Tornado 3.2 появилась опция `default_handler_class`: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.Application.

Небольшой хак -- размещаете последним обработчиком запросов такой, который обрабатывает любой URL:

```
tornado.web.Application([..., (r"/.*",  NotFoundRequestHandler, ...))],
```

В нем выставляете код ошибки и выводите все, что необходимо:

```
def get(self):
    self.set_status(http.client.NOT_FOUND)
    self.render(...)
```

Comment: в принципе так и сделал пока nginx не настроен, но спасибо, что откликнулись=)

Answer (score 0):

Там темплейты точно где-то есть. Найдите папку с темплейтами и увидите файлы, изменив и отредактировав, которые сможете набросать свой стиль.

Comment: 2.4, но могу поставить 3.1.1, не принципиально на данный момент.

Comment: сейчас у себя на 3.1 поменяю и отпишусь как.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-tornado/upI5hrejdz4
вот тут все написано! у меня заработало! проверяй у себя!